# why ActionListener is not implemented when creating GUI using window builder in eclipse?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Im using window builder to create a front end GUI and I get the following automatically generated code. In the below code I cannot find the statement that ***implements ActionListener*** for the button click event. Its directly calling add addActionListener and actionPerformed without the statement ***Public class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener*** as I learned in the tutorials.

```
public class gui extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    gui frame = new gui();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public gui() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 386, 451);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionListener` is called as an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) here:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

so your `gui` class doesn't need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

window builder always create anonymous class (for Listeners) so that you don't need to implements Listener in other class or in same class. if you dont want to use anonymous class  then you have to modify the code manually.